# Program crashes when trying to add node to linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I wrote this program, and it crashes when I compile. It says the executable has stopped working and Windows is trying to find a solution. I believe the issue is somewhere in this addPage function I wrote to add a node to a linked list, but I'm not sure what is causing the issue.

```
void initPage(struct page *head, string programName) {

// Assign Properties of the First Node in the Linked List
head->programName = programName;
head->nextPage = NULL;

}

void addPage(struct page *head, string programName) {

// Initialize First Page if Not Initialized
if (head == NULL) {
    initPage(head, programName);
    return;
}

// Setup the New Page
page *newPage = new page;
newPage->programName = programName;
newPage->nextPage = NULL;

// Set the Pointer to the Beginning of the Linked List
page *current = head;

// While Traversing the Linked List
while(current) {

    // If the End of the List is Reached, Append the Page
    if (current->nextPage == NULL) {
        current->nextPage = newPage;
        return;
    }

    // Grab the Next Page (If not at the End of the Page)
    current = current->nextPage;
}

}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Rinzler http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Have you tried running in a debugger to catch the crash in action? Where does it happen? Do the involved variables look okay? How do you call the function? When do you call the function? From where do you call the function? What are the arguments you pass to the function? Does it crash the first call? The second? Seemingly randomly?

Answer (score 5):

This:

```
if (head == NULL) {
    initPage(head, programName);
```

passes a null to initPage, which then immediately dereferences it.  Boom.

Tip: ALWAYS check a pointer for null before using it.

Also, initPage is an incomplete copy of code in addPage.  It seems better to always run the code in addPage that creates the new page (i.e., don't call initPage() at all) and then, once you've got a page, test head for null to see if you should just set head to the new page or iterate the list looking for the end.

Comment: How should I change my code to fix this? I'm surprised the issue was there because I tried running it before with that part commented out and it actually worked, but maybe it was doing something else.

Comment: Step through the code yourself - it's good practice.  I think it was working because the "page *current = head;

// While Traversing the Linked List
while(current) {... sequence won't enter the loop if head is null so therefore does nothing (but doesn't crash).

Comment: I'm still not quite understanding what's causing the crash.

Comment: @Rinzler If `head` is null, then using `head->programName` in any way is an error that will result in some form of crash.

Comment: @Biffen Right, I understood that and deleted intPage(head, programName) so there's just a return statement. However, it still crashes. What else should I be doing because I'm at a loss.

Comment: I found the original error by stepping through the code one line at a time determining which value each variable would take.  I suggest that you do the same to the revised code.